# Convert an integer to 4 bytes without bitshift operators

Tags: c, lua, glsl

This code is applicable to either GLSL or C due to virtually identical syntax. Before GLSL 1.3, bitshift operators were not present and I am aiming for backwards compatibility to GLSL 1.2.

```
float lut[3] = {256,65536,16777216};


vec4 getBytes(float n)
 {
   vec4 bytes;
   bytes.x = floor(n / lut[2]);
   bytes.y = floor((n- bytes.x*(lut[2]) )/ lut[1]);
   bytes.z = floor((n - bytes.y*(lut[1]) - bytes.x*lut[2] )/ lut[0]) ;
   bytes.w = n - bytes.z*lut[0] - bytes.y*lut[1] - bytes.x*lut[2];
   return bytes;
 }

 float getid(vec4 bytes)
 {
   return bytes.w + bytes.z*lut[0]+ bytes.y*lut[1] + bytes.x*lut[2];
 }
```

This code will be used to pack a value greater than 8 bits into an 8-bit texture with 4 channels.

I also ported the code to Lua to run a unit test.

```
 lut = {256,65536,16777216}
 function getBytes(n)

   bytes = {}
   bytes.x = math.floor(n / lut[3]);
   bytes.y = math.floor((n- bytes.x*(lut[3]) )/ lut[2]);
   bytes.z = math.floor((n - bytes.y*(lut[2]) - bytes.x*lut[3] )/ lut[1]) ;
   bytes.w = n - bytes.z*lut[1] - bytes.y*lut[2] - bytes.x*lut[3];
   return bytes
 end

 function getid(bytes)

   return bytes.w + bytes.z*lut[1]+ bytes.y*lut[2] + bytes.x*lut[3]
 end

for i=1,math.pow(2,24),1 do 
  if not (getid(getBytes(i)) == i) then

    print("Fail " .. i)
  end

end
```

Comment: I am not  familiar with GLSL: What is the reason to pass an integer as `float` to the function?

Comment: GLSL 1.2 does not support integers properly(only simulates them with floats) so using a float makes no difference and is more explicit.

Comment: @J.H : Gotta ask this: why ist the array called lut?

Comment: @GregorOphey It's short for LookUp Table, I presume.

Comment: @GregorOphey Yes it does stand for look up table

Comment: What is `vec4`?

Comment: @JL2210 a vector of 4 elements, to represent the 4 bytes

Comment: @J.H Can you provide the relevant `#include` or `typedef`?

Comment: These types are standard GLSL types. GLSL does not support #includes. They are defined by the language. They're pretty straight forward, though. `vec4` = `union { struct { float x; float y; float z; float w; }; struct { float r; float g; float b; float a; }; float [4] };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a ton that can be improved here, but:

- `lut` should be made `const`
- Due to implicit promotion, `lut` can be stored as integers instead of floats. Your expressions should evaluate to the same thing.
- Consider representing your `lut` constants in hexadecimal (`0x`) format - or as `1 << x` notation.
- Your `lut` doesn't strictly need to be an array; you're not iterating over it or indexing it dynamically. As such, you may be better off simply making individually-named constants such as `XL`, `YL`, `ZL`.